# Autowired service null in AspectJ aspect on a Spring Boot / Swing standalone app

Tags: java, swing, spring-boot, aspectj, autowired

I currently have a Swing application running on Spring Boot, launched with the following code :

```
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Something.class);
application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
application.run(args);
```

I have enabled the java agents for aspectjweaver and spring-instrument and enabled load-time weaving since i need to target private methods.  My aspect is for logging so i need to autowire a logging service that writes entries to a log table in the database.  The aspect class is annotated with @Aspect and @Component.  I am trying to autowire the service with the @Autowired annotation but the value is null when any pointcut executes.  I assume this has to do with some sort of other mechanism than the Spring context instantiating these aspects but i cannot figure out how to correctly autowire my required service.  I tried implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface but it did not work either.

Does anyone have experience with autowiring services into AspectJ aspects on a Swing application?  I have another project that runs on Spring Boot and Spring MVC and this works out of the box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue turned out to be partly multi-threading related but what I was mostly missing was this :

```
@Bean
public MessagingLogger messagingLogger(LogEntryService logEntryService) 
{
    MessagingLogger aspect = Aspects.aspectOf(MessagingLogger.class);

    aspect.setLogEntryService(logEntryService);

    return aspect;
}
```

This is how I was able to "inject" my service into my aspect.  The second part of my issue turned out to be that i wasn't careful enough in my multi-threading setup (lots of background processes in this app) and i was trying to use the aspect while Spring wasn't even done creating all the services.